# How To: Hover Over Shape Shows TextBox

Tags: excel, vb.net, hover, draw, shapes

I am trying to make it so when a user hovers over a triangle as shown below, a textbox pops up with certain information pertaining to that triangle. [image]

Triangles are drawn with the following function...

```
Public Sub drawTriangle(theRow As Integer, theColumn As Integer, Optional myColor As System.Drawing.Color = Nothing)
        myColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
        Dim theShape As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Shape = xlWorkSheet.Shapes.AddShape(MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeIsoscelesTriangle, (xlWorkSheet.Cells(theRow, theColumn)).Left + 18, (xlWorkSheet.Cells(theRow, theColumn)).Top, 15, 14)
        theShape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = ToBgr(myColor)
        theShape.Line.ForeColor.RGB = ToBgr(myColor)

    End Sub
```

I haven't been able to find any examples or good documentation about how I would do this, so I thought I'd ask here. Any and all help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Is this information read-only? If so, can you make it a comment object attached to the triangle?

Comment: @vbnet3d it would be read only... What you're describing sounds like It would be perfect as long as it shows up when hovered over and disappears when it's not hovered over

Comment: According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.addcomment.aspx), you can add a comment to a range - not sure about a shape.

Comment: @vbnet3d I see what you're saying and that would work perfectly... How would I go about getting the range from a cell location say (5,5). In an example I just used I did `xlWorkSheet.Range("E5").AddComment("Testing this out")` but how would I turn (5,5) into a letter and number like that?

Comment: @vbnet3d also if you answer in a... answer to my post I'll accept it as you've solved my issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.addcomment.aspx), comments can be added to ranges. For this to work for your application, you simply need to select the range that corresponds to your shape, and then call AddComment().

The numeric coordinates of a cell can be used to determine the actual Cell name (i.e. E5) by using code like the following([source](http://www.howtobuildsoftware.com/index.php/how-do/bw6L/vbnet-excel-excel-cell-location-using-row-and-column-numbers-vbnet)):

```
address = xlWorkSheet.Cells(RowVariable, ColVariable).Address
```

This can be followed up with:

```
xlWorkSheet.Range(address).AddComment("This is a comment")
```

Comment: Awesome, I really appreciate it. Got it working... Have to ask, any way to make the comment box Bigger or the font in the comment box smaller?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any experience with that - but since it can be done manually, I assume it must be possible through interop. [Start here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.comment_properties.aspx), and note that there is a `Shape` property for the comment. I expect that what you need is probably buried in there somewhere.

Comment: Ah that's beautiful. Thanks again!!